# Remove zeros from array with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, photoshop-script

I get back a histogram array from Photoshop as a string

```
 var rArray = activeDocument.channels["Red"].histogram.toString()
```

For those of you without Photoshop, just ignore that detail as it'll be an array something like

```
66500,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0...
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,750,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0...
```

Currently I've got a function to loop over the (string as an) array and remove any zero values. However, I'm sure it can be done with a regex. Only I'm picking up one of the zeros of of the number I want to keep.

```
.replace(/(,0)/g,"")
```

only that returns

```
665010000
75
```

instead of

```
66500
750
```

The expected output is to eliminate all zeros

```
66500,10000
750
```

See it [here on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kX9NxF/1/)

I'm pretty sure this can me done as regex only, I don't know how to specify "0," OR "0$" zero AND a comma OR zero and ENDSTRING literally.

Comment: Try `.replace(/,?\b0\b,?/g, '')`. Or, `.replace(/^(?:0,)*(\d+).*/, '$1')`.

Comment: Does it _have_ to be a regex? Can you not filter out the zeroes using `.filter` on the array itself, and then call `.toString` on the resulting array?

Comment: Although the brackets not needed on your first regEx, it should work.  Can you do a snippet showing this behaviour.

Comment: @Phillip Sadly, there's no filter functionality in ECMAScript for Photoshop - which is what I'm using.

Comment: @Keith I've added a regex101 link if that will suffice instead of a JSfiddle (which I've not used)

Comment: Yes, in your regex101 link just put `^0|,0`

Comment: Perhaps a variation on Wiktor's suggestion `\b0,|,?\b0\b` https://regex101.com/r/UHmPL4/1

Comment: Any feedback on my two solutions in the top comment?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've just done a quick test. The first one returns numbers with zeroes on the end. ie 84747000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000. The second looks more promising, but loses the last non-zero element in the array.

Comment: Btw you can easily add `.filter()` and similar via polyfill

Answer (score 0):

The pattern /^0|,0/g should do the trick.

check here:
regexr.com/5akbq

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^(?:0,)+|(?:,0)+$|\b0,
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zLqpnG/1)

**Details**

- `^(?:0,)+` - one or more occurrences of `0,` substring from the string start
- `|` - or
- `(?:,0)+$` - one or more occurrences of `,0` substring till the string end
- `|` - or
- `\b0,` - a word boundary followed with `0,` substring.